# Performance benefit from defining functions before jQuery(document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, function

Is there a performance benefit to be found from defining functions before `jQuery(document).ready`?

Code A:

```
(function($){
'use strict';

  function myfunction() {
   // some code
  }

  $(document).ready(function($) {

    //some other code

    myfunction();

  });


})(jQuery);
```

Code B:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  'use strict';

    function myfunction() {
     // some code
    }

    //some other code

    myfunction();

  });
```

Will **Code A** be faster than **Code B**?
My thinking is that in the case of **Code A**, the browser may regsiter and parse the function faster. I'm a bit out of my league here.

Comment: That should make no difference at all, because of “hoisting”. The JS interpreter extracts the variable and function declarations _before_ is starts running your code. http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/variable-and-function-hoisting

Comment: Not sure you're going to see much benefit, but the second is definitely easier to read and thus maintain.

Comment: @vol7ron why not? The question was if either of those two ways of declaring the function would make the whole thing faster (_“the browser may regsiter and parse the function faster”_) - and to that I would say, no, because of hoisting.

Comment: @vol7ron _“if you define the internal function in a broader scope, the parser no longer has to scan and hoist it when the ready function is called”_ – this is not how hoisting works. The parser does not start to parse what is inside the ready function only when it is about to execute that function; it does all that before it starts executing _any_ of the code. Think of hoisting as a craftsman going, “ok, let’s get an overview of what tools (functions) we got available to work with here”, _before_ they start to do the actual work.

Comment: @CBroe agh, I think I confused modern browsers with an old developmental JavaScript engine.  My bad — I'll delete those wrong comments.  Hoisting only moves variables/functions to the top of the scope, but the parsing is done earlier.

Comment: @CBroe *"The parser does not start to parse what is inside the ready function only when it is about to execute that function; it does all that before it starts executing any of the code."*. Assuming this is correct, this is exactly the answer i was looking for. So I'm sure I got this right, hoisting is done globally and regarless of scope, and the scope is then applied. So the location of the function is meaningless as far as performance is concearned. Correct? If you write a proper answer, I'll select it so it can help others.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no difference from a performance perspective. The functions will be stored in memory before execution, regardless of their position in the code.

More on this topic:

- https://medium.com/dailyjs/javascript-basics-the-execution-context-and-the-lexical-environment-3505d4fe1be2
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting

Comment: `The functions will be stored in memory before execution` there is a difference in when they are stored in memory and thus there is an impact for the performance of the `ready` execution.

Comment: Thnk you for the good resources, but I'm not sure i get how that applies here, since in `Code B` `myfunction()` is already at the top of it's scope. The issue is wether the JS engine will parse and interpret `myfunction()` after `document.ready` of before, even if it's encapsulated in `document.ready`.